# Better approach to integrate multiple types of Interfaces

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, software-design, abstraction

I have, say, two devices.

```
class Device1{
  public:
  int GetData(){
  //...
  }
};

class Device2{
  public:
  bool GetData(){
  //...
  }
};
```

I have a a C# style timer class that runs a std::thread periodically.
Time being, I am showing only a one-time call, rather than the periodic ones.

A Timer class looks like this:

```
class Timer {
    public:
        Timer(long long period,
            std::function<int()> f):
            m_timeperiod(period * 1000000){
                
        m_enable = true;
        m_thd = std::thread (f);
    }
        virtual ~Timer(){}
        void Wait()
        {
            m_thd.join();
        }

    private:
        long long m_timeperiod;
        std::atomic<bool> m_enable;
        //std::function <int()> m_action;
        void Loop();
        std::thread m_thd;
    };
```

The main looks like:

```
int main()
{
    Device1 d1;
    std::function<int()> fnCaller = std::bind(&Device1::GetData, &d1);
    Timer tmr(1,fnCaller);
    tmr.Wait();
    std::cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine for Device1, but I have to create a new Timer class for Device2.

```
class Timer2 {
    public:
        Timer(long long period,
            std::function<bool()> f):
            m_timeperiod(period * 1000000){
                
        m_enable = true;
        m_thd = std::thread (f);
    }
        virtual ~Timer(){}
        void Wait()
        {
            m_thd.join();
        }

    private:
        long long m_timeperiod;
        std::atomic<bool> m_enable;
        //std::function <int()> m_action;
        void Loop();
        std::thread m_thd;
    };
```

Later I might need to create a newer one for Device3, so on and so forth.
What can I do to have a scalable solution?

Comment: `Timer2` looks identical to `Timer`? Why do you need a second class?

Comment: `Timer2` has `std::function<bool()> f)` as parameter to constructor. `Timer` has `std::function<int()> f)`

Comment: Ah, ok. Any reason not to just make it a template?

Comment: What I am thinking is:
I want to design the Task irrespective of return types of the sensors. Something on the following lines.
`class Timer {`
`public:`
`Timer(long long period,`
`std::function<void()> f):`
`m_timeperiod(period * 1000000){`
`}`
`//...    `
`};`

Comment: Have an ITask interface and a concrete implementation like:
`class ITask{`
`public:`
`void GetData() =0;`
`};`

`class Task:public ITask{`
`public:`
`Task(Isensor &_sensor, IRepository &_rep):sensor(_sensor), rep(_rep){}`
`void GetData()override`
`{`
`rep.SaveData(sensor.GetData());`
`}`
`private:`
`Isensor &sensor;`
`IRepository &rep;`
`};`

Comment: I couldn't figure out how can I unify the different interfaces `Device1::GetData`, `Device2::GetData` to `Isensor::GetData`.
But I believe I have missed the fact that I need to provide the return type to `Isensor::GetData` and `IRepository::SaveData`;
Thank you for your comment. I need to think clearer.

Comment: There are two ways to unify them: ignore the return type or use a common type as return type for all, e.g. `std::variant`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, thank you. I haven't checked it yet, but will try it out.